# Webview unable to render frameset

Tags: webview, android-webview, frameset

I am trying to load a webpage inside web view - https://netbanking.hdfcbank.com/netbanking/. I can see the dom rendered but the height of frame is 0.

```
<html><head>
<title>Welcome to HDFC Bank NetBanking</title>
<script language="javascript">
    var daemon          = 'NETBANKING';
    var p_remoteaddress = '';
    var RsaAuthReq      = '';

    var l_path = window.location.pathname;

    if(l_path == undefined || l_path == '' || l_path.indexOf("/netbanking") < 0){
        window.location.href = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host +"/netbanking";
    }

</script>
</head>
    <frameset border="false" frameborder="O" framespacing="0" rows="*" cols="*">
        <frameset border="false" frameborder="O" framespacing="0" rows="*,30" cols="*">
            <frame marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" name="login_page" src="RSLogin.html?v=7" noresize="true" scrolling="yes">
            <frame marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" name="footer" src="footer.html" noresize="true" scrolling="no">
        </frameset>
    </frameset>

</html>
```

I can see the same is getting rendered in other apps webview and chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The webview was wrap_content, changed it to match_parent.